# How to add static files using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My question is how to add static files like CSS and image files so that I can use them. I am using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf. I looked at various posts on this subject, but they did't help me, so I am asking. As per those posts, I put my CSS and image file in the `resources/static/css` and `resources/static/images directory`.

[image: demo]

Under `templates` (under `webapp/WEB-INF/templates`) is where all my HTML files are stored, the ones who want to use the CSS and image files.

I have the following `LoginApplicationConfig` file. The very two bottom methods I included so that my HTML files could use the styles and image files:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.myapp.spring.*" })
@Import(value = { LoginSecurityConfig.class })
public class LoginApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
      public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
      public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/css").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/images").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

Then in my index.html file, I included the following line so I could include the style file (using thymeleaf):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/stylesmd.css}" type="text/css">
```

But I keep getting the error that the stylesmd.css failed to load.

My questions:

1. Is the placement of my styles and image files correct. That is, what folders should I specifically put them in. I tried various location like under the `webapp` and `WEB-INF` directory but that didn't work.
2. Are the bottom two methods in `LoginApplicationConfig`required? In addition, I was a bit confused on what to include in the `addResourceHandler(...)` method and what in the `addResourceLocations(...)` method.
3. Is my reference to the style sheet (using thymeleaf) correct?

I am aware a lot of content already exists on this question, but that did't work for me, so that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I made it work.
Only one line suffice.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
```

And

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/your.css" th:href="@{/static/css/your.css}"/>
</head>
```

If it keeps failing, try to move your "templates" folder into the resources folder as a subfolder.